# How do I make media queries work for Gmail signature?

Tags: media-queries, gmail-api

I am trying to use media queries for a GMail email signature.

The media queries seem to simply not work at all, even when this simple example is copy pasted as is: https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css#example_2

Litmus is being used to test this, and whether it's desktop or mobile; Android or iOS; the media queries simply have no effect.

I followed the guidelines in the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701247/how-do-i-write-a-media-query-for-gmail), but no luck.

Is it even possible to use media queries for GMail signatures?

PS: I am setting the signature programmatically using the following:

- https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client
- https://apis.google.com/js/api.js

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] and explain the exact issue you are having. **but no luck.** does not describe the problem

Answer (score 0):

- [CSS Media Queries](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css#css_media_queries) adjust the styling of the html body of an email
- The signature is not part of the html body of an email and thus, media queries don't affect it
- What you can do is to retrieve the signature programmatically with

`var signature = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.get("me", "your email or alias").signature;`

- In the next step you can add the signature retrieved in this way manually to the html body of your email:

`var signature = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.get("me", "your email or alias").signature;`

**Thus, you will be able to apply Css media Queries to the signature by making it part of the html body.**

See the full solution in the [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62993125/11599789).