# MailApp automated emails don't include user's email signature

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail-api

So I've created a few spreadsheets that are used by myself and several co-workers to send automated emails. However, I'm noticing that none of these emails include the users' email signature.

I'm having a hard time finding any info on this, the only [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62962564/how-to-include-the-users-gmail-signature-when-using-gmailapp-sendemail-from-goog) I found references the GmailApp, but on [Sending email from Google Sheets](https://spreadsheet.dev/send-email-from-google-sheets) it says to use MailApp and not GmailApp so for all my scripts I've been using MailApp.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: What Developer's page says "to use MailApp and not GmailApp"?

Comment: It is recommended here to "Use the MailApp instead of the GmailApp to send emails" https://spreadsheet.dev/send-email-from-google-sheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to automatically read a Gmail signature, you must use the Advanced Gmail Service or the Gmail API through Url Fetch Service. I think that the easier way to proceed is that you use the default OAuth scopes, usually the most permissive, then when you finish to use your script unauthorize it. You can do this automatically by adding `ScriptApp.invalidateAuth();` at the end of your script. Note: I haven't used this method yet. If you decide to use it, verify that the authorization was removed.

---

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62993125/1595451) from the referred Q/A uses the Advanced Gmail Service, not  GmailApp. Anyway, instead of using the default OAuth scope that gives "complete" access to your script to your Gmail mailbox you might use one more specific. The options are listed here -> https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/get. The more restrictive scope is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly`.

The complete list of the OAuth scopes for Gmail API ->  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes