How to Send Email via Python's smtplib with Gmail Signature Automatically Included?
I am trying to send an email through Python's smtplib using my Gmail account, and I have already configured a signature in my Gmail settings. However, when the email is sent from my Python script, the signature that I registered in Gmail does not appear in the sent email.
Here’s the Python script I’m using:
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Gmail credentials
gmail_user = "myemail@gmail.com"
gmail_password = "myapppassword"

# Email subject and body
subject = "Awesome Email"
body = """Hi There,

I hope this message finds you well.

I'm sending you a bulk email with my Gmail signature

Best regards,
Dustin
"""

# Function to send emails
def send_emails(recipients):
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)

        for recipient in recipients:
            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg["From"] = gmail_user
            msg["To"] = recipient
            msg["Subject"] = subject
            msg.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain"))
            server.sendmail(gmail_user, recipient, msg.as_string())

        server.quit()
        print("Emails sent successfully!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

# List of recipient emails
recipients = ["recipient1@example.com", "recipient2@example.com"]

# Trigger the email sending
send_emails(recipients)

Problem:
Even though I have a signature configured in my Gmail account (which works fine when I send emails through the Gmail web interface), the emails sent through my Python script using smtplib do not include my Gmail signature.
Question:
How can I send emails from Python (via smtplib) and ensure that my Gmail signature is automatically appended to the outgoing emails? Do I need to use a different approach, or is there a way to achieve this using smtplib?

A signature (those few lines with text at the bottom) is not appended to a submitted message, but it is automatically added by the message composer immediately before the message is submitted to a SMTP server for delivery. Unless gmail is doing something really non-standard (I'm not using it, so I cannot rule it out), your program is responsible for submitting the final version of your message to the server.

I tried and searched for a workaround for the given code above, but based on my research why not use app script instead, this is a similar problem and check the  first answer.
Adding a signature is a setting on the clientside of the Gmail Web UI, it is not available via API
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62962564/how-to-include-the-users-gmail-signature-when-using-gmailapp-sendemail-from-goog

So is there any solutions to resolve this?
